# MS SQL and Firebird integration with SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

Prepares the integration of two systems. The first is an ERP based on the MS SQL database and the second is a program for optimizing pipe cutting (cutlogic) based on the Firebird database. I base my integration on SQL Server Intgeration Services (SSIS). From ERP, I send information about inventory levels. And here comes the problem. In ERP, we store information about a given inventory in the form of the sum of the number of meters for a given batch of inventory, e.g. 80 meters. Each stock has a specific commercial length recorded on the stock card, e.g. 10 m. So the ERP says that I have 80 meters, but in fact there are 8 pipes, each 10 meters long. And in this form I am sending it to firebrd. And it works for me, I have a SQL query prepared for it. But I have a problem with removing items from stock in a firberd-based system. Because in ERP I have information that I have removed 65 meters and now I have to make the same move in Firebird, but there I have it broken down into individual pieces and for a given batch and stock number (because this is the key) I have more such pieces. How can I do this. Do you have any ideas?

I tried to make a query to assign an id number from firebird to the data from my ERP, but the join I use returns all the payments and I only need those whose sum will give me the amount from ERP. I can't use stored procedures so the temporary tables are gone. Maybe I can do it somehow in SSIS itself?